# ERROR - An error occurred while running subprocess cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic4, angular8

I am trying to run the ionic app for android but it gives me below error.

[image]

I'm trying to solve this issue with some help provides by FAQ but it doesn't work !

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution from a related solved topic: 
The solution is:

- ionic platform rm android
- ionic platform add android@latest
- ionic resources
- ionic run android